How to deal with JPA Speficication when use @OneToMany relation?
The code is a simple example that helps explain the problem I have.
These are the entities I have:
@Entity
@Data
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childs;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idParent", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Parent parent;

    private Boolean active;
}

This is a simple specification:
public class ParentSpecification {
    public static Specification<Parent> filterBy() {
        return Specification.where(childName(true));
    }

    private static Specification<Parent> childName(Boolean active) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(Parent_.CHILDS).get(Child_.ACTIVE), active);
    }
}

Take this example data:
Parent              Child

| id |     | id | active | idParent |
| -- |     | -- | ------ | -------- |
| 1  |     | 1  |  true  |     1    |          
| 2  |     | 2  |  true  |     1    |

The problem is that I have duplicate Parent in result using specification:
RESULT<Parent>

| id | idChild |
| -- | ------- |
|  1 |    1    |
|  1 |    2    |

This is the SQL generated by the specification:
select p1_0.id,
from parent p1_0 
join child c1_0 on p1_0.id=c1_0.id_parent 
where c1_0.active=true 

What would I have to do to not have duplicate results?
